# Picturebox.click acting different than button.click?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I want to loop through Datagridview and search for checkboxes with True value.
Both Controls (Button and Picturebox) have the exact same code, but they act differently.
If I click on the PictureBox, it won't detect either the last checked row or the first, but when I click on the button first, it works then as it should. (Button however works perfectly every time)

What could be the issue with this?

Code:

```
Private Sub PictureBoxVorgangAnlegen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBoxVorgangAnlegen.Click
    For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("Auswahl").Value = True Then
            MsgBox("true " & DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("Position").Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `Click` event handlers acting differently at all. They are both doing exactly the same thing. The difference is that a `Button` can receive focus and does when you click it while a `PictureBox` cannot and does not. That means that the actions that the grid performs when it loses focus have occurred when your `Button` control's `Click` handler is executed but not when the `Click` event handler for your `PictureBox` is executed. If you were to, for instance, click into a `TextBox` first and then click the `PictureBox`, you'd find the result would be the same as if you had clicked the `Button`.

You need to do something to force those actions to occur. Without having tested, I think that calling the `EndEdit` method of the grid should be enough. You may need to call the form's `Validate` method as well or instead but I'd go with `EndEdit` as a first option.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, calling EndEdit before my code solved the problem. Thank you very much